# Program doesn't stop after reading from pipe

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I am trying to understand pipes. I have this small program which uses a pipe to send a message from the parent process to its child. The child recieves all the 3 messages, but instead of exiting, after reading the last message it hangs. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

PS: I noticed that if I would sleep for 2 seconds in the while loop from the parent, it would work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){

    int desc[2];
    pipe(desc);

    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        while(1){
            sleep(1);
            char buffer[16];
            if(read(desc[0], buffer, 16) != 16){
                printf("Error or finished");
                exit(0);
            };
            printf("Child: message recieved - '%s'\n", buffer);
        }
        close(desc[1]);
    }
    if(pid > 0){
        int i=0;
        while(i <= 2){
            char buffer[100];
            i++; char x[10];
            strcpy(buffer, "Hello, child!");
            sprintf(x, " %d", i);
            strcat(buffer, x);
            if(write(desc[1], buffer, 16) != 16){
                printf("Error");
                exit(0);
            };
        }
        close(desc[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to close the unused ends of the pipes in both the parent and child processes. Actually your child possess reading and writing parts of the pipe, so it cannot detect the end-of-file as there exists a writer (itself!), so it is blocked in the read. Change your code to:

```
if(pid == 0){
    close(desc[1]); // Child is not a writer, so close the write part immediately!
    while(1){
      ...
    }
}
if(pid > 0){
    close(desc[0]); // Parent is not a reader, so close the read part immediately!
    int i=0;
    while(i <= 2){
      ...
    }
}
```

Remember that on a pipe, end-of-file is "nothing more to read in the pipe" **and** "no more writer".

Comment: To play devil's advocate, OP's code does close the unused ends of the pipe in the parent and child processes, however that only happens after the loop. Does that mean those statements are never reached?

Comment: @uzluisf You need to close them **before** the loop. If not they were not closed and the loop will be unable to detect the EOF. Condition for EOF, is: nothing to read **and** no more writer. So you need to cose the unecessary writers... Same for the converse.

Comment: Got it, thanks Jean!

Answer (score 5):

You must close pipe ends correctly. Reader will hang until all write ends of the pipe are closed.

```
if(pid == 0){
    close(desc[1]); // close write end in reader
    while(1){
        ...
        read(desc[0], buffer, 16);
        ...
    }
}
if(pid > 0){
    int i=0;
    close(desc[0]); // close read end in writer; not required, but makes code cleaner
    while(i <= 2){
      ...
      write(desc[1], buffer, 16);
      ...
    }
    close(desc[1]); // close write end in writer
}
```

Comment: You are right about "close write end in writer" but after that point, the parent will exit and thus the file descriptor will be closed anyway. But +1 for being explicit. The exit mechanism of child doesn't seem natural either. But that's a different issue, I guess.